# Div not showing up in Html and Css

Tags: html, css

the divs won't show up, any ideas why? I'm guessing I've done some rookie mistake somewhere

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<style>

#fullcontainer {
  background: black;
}

</style>

<body>
  <div id="fullcontainer">

      <div class="boxinfo" id="box1"></div>
      <div class="boxinfo" id="box2"></div>
      <div class="boxinfo" id="box3"></div>
      <div class="boxinfo" id="box4"></div>

  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: You did not include boxinfo style in your code, does boxinfo have any width/height, flex etc? Does your divs has content in them?

Answer (score 0):

The divs don't show up visually, because they don't have any content to show or given CSS dimension.
Because of that their current `height` is 0.

If you would for example give them some textual content, then that will be shown.

Due to the black background-color of their parent `#fullcontainer`, i have set the containers `color` to white to be able to read their textual content :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<style>

#fullcontainer {
  background: black;
  color: white;
}

</style>

<body>
  <div id="fullcontainer">

      <div class="boxinfo" id="box1">Box 1</div>
      <div class="boxinfo" id="box2">Box 2</div>
      <div class="boxinfo" id="box3">Box 3</div>
      <div class="boxinfo" id="box4">Box 4</div>

  </div>
</body>
```